# Subquery Order by Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, sql-order-by

My Database has 3 Tables, Device,Postal_Address and Company.

Every Device has an Company_ID, and for every company there is an address. The problem is, the old address is still there if i change it, its everytime making a new entry for this. So if i select all devices with address i get some entrys doubled.

```
select d.device,
 ( 
           select postalcode_address from 
           ( 
                select  
                     pa.postalcode_address,   
                     row_number() over (order by pa.last_update desc) r,
                     pa.company_id
                from   
                     postal_address pa   
           )  
             where  company_id=c.company_id
            AND r=1

      ) as Postcode
from device d,company c,
where d.company_id = c.company_id(+)
```

I have tried it with order the address withlast_update, but its getting me nothing back, where is my error? so i need the newest entry in the postal_address for my company_id.

Comment: We don't have your table structures nor your data, so it's impossible to guess what might be going wrong. Please update your question to include the table structures, sample data that exhibits your issue and what you want the output to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your row_number() analytic call is getting the row number across all companies, so you'll only get a match for the most-recently-changed company; no other company will get `r = 1`. You need to partition by the company ID:

```
row_number() over (partition by pa.company_id order by pa.last_update desc) r,
```

Or move the `where company_id=c.company_id` inside that nested subquery; but that doesn't work in some versions of Oracle (the `c` alias might not be visible).

---

I wouldn't use a subquery to get the column value within the select list at all here though; you could use the same row number check as an inline view and join to it:

```
select d.device, pa.postalcode_address
from device d
left join company c on c.company_id = d.company_id
left join (
  select company_id, postalcode_address,
    row_number() over (partition by company_id order by last_update desc) rn
  from postal_address
) pa on pa.company_id = c.company_id and pa.rn = 1;
```